# Getting a very general IOException with HttpUrlConnection

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, web-scraping, httpurlconnection

I'm having some problems with HttpUrlConnection, When I run the device (Gingerbread HTC Desire) LogCat displays the very general:

`11-23 14:26:19.394: WARN/System.err(6591): java.io.IOException: Error connecting`

I've added AsyncTask to try and remedy the problem, but there seems to be no difference.  I've shown the full logcat at the bottom, here is the class in question (shortened it up a bit and set the url to google (same results):

```
public class JSoupHelper {
    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://www.google.co.uk";

    public JSoupHelper() {
        new Login().execute(LOGIN_URL);
    }
    private class Login extends AsyncTask<String, String, InputStream>{
        @Override
        protected InputStream doInBackground(String... params) {
            String url = params[0];
            Log.d("JSoup-LoginHelper","Starting background AsyncTask on "+url);
            try {
                InputStream is = OpenHttpConnection(url);
                return is;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
     private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = null;
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        Log.d("JSoup-OHTTPSC","Connecting to "+urlString);
        try{
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.connect();
            Log.d("JSoup-OHTTPSC","Connected to "+urlString);

            int response = conn.getResponseCode();
            if (response == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                in = conn.getInputStream();
            }
            conn.disconnect();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new IOException("Error connecting");
        }
        return in;
    }
}
```

LOGCAT:

```
11-23 14:25:59.214: DEBUG/JSoup-LoginHelper(6591): Starting background AsyncTask on http://www.google.co.uk
11-23 14:25:59.234: DEBUG/JSoup-OHTTPSC(6591): Connecting to http://www.google.co.uk
           ~~~~ 20 secs pass ~~~~
11-23 14:26:19.394: WARN/System.err(6591): java.io.IOException: Error connecting
11-23 14:26:19.394: WARN/System.err(6591): at com.example.untitled1.JSoupHelper.OpenHttpsConnection(JSoupHelper.java:67)
11-23 14:26:19.394: WARN/System.err(6591): at com.example.untitled1.JSoupHelper.access$100(JSoupHelper.java:12)
11-23 14:26:19.394: WARN/System.err(6591): at com.example.untitled1.JSoupHelper$Login.doInBackground(JSoupHelper.java:40)
11-23 14:26:19.394: WARN/System.err(6591): at com.example.untitled1.JSoupHelper$Login.doInBackground(JSoupHelper.java:34)
11-23 14:26:19.394: WARN/System.err(6591): at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java)
11-23 14:26:19.394: WARN/System.err(6591): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
11-23 14:26:19.394: WARN/System.err(6591): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
11-23 14:26:19.394: WARN/System.err(6591): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
11-23 14:26:19.394: WARN/System.err(6591): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
11-23 14:26:19.394: WARN/System.err(6591): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1027)
11-23 14:26:23.077: INFO/htcfs-main(6749): main()
```

My goal here is to actually acquire an InputStream and parse it using JSoup via HttpsUrlConnection, login using post and then save the cookies and sessions variables, then using the cookies I can do some proper scraping of the website and store the results into a Sqlite db... but one step at a time (especially with my lack of debugging skills and general Java skills).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your exception is very general because it is made this way by yourself. instead of throwing a new exeption with little to no information, print the stackTrace where you are or throw ex directly.

Comment: basically, by creating a new Exception, you loose the existing stack trace and the message. this is not really recommended

Comment: Thanks very much njzk2! It actually works now and the response code is 200... I'm a bit confused on how catching an exception was stopping it from working though.